# bash like autocompletion for ssh command in zsh shell with /etc/hosts file?

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, autocomplete, hosts

zsh is great so far.
I am using zsh-completions but still I am unable to get autocompletion for ssh commands like in bash as shown in below screenshot:

[image: BASH vs ZSH]

How to get hostnames from /etc/hosts for **ssh  | scp | telnet** command autocompletion in zsh shell ?

Update 1:

https://github.com/sunlei/zsh-ssh : This SSH completion offers a greater array of features in comparison to the default SSH completion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zsh won't offer you host completions until you enable its full completion system. You can do so by adding the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Once initialized, Zsh's completion system will retrieve host names from `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`, `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and `Host ...`/`Name ...` lines in ssh config files. Have a look inside those files.

Note that if you have aliased `ssh` to another command, `zsh` will offer completions for that other command. If you want it to offer the same completions for that other command as those for `ssh`, you need to tell it to do so, with something like this:

```
alias ssh=<some other command>
compdef _ssh <some other-command>=ssh
```

Alternatively, you can use a function instead of an alias:

```
ssh() {
  <some other-command> "$@"
}
```

Comment: yes... I have this already in my .zshrc file. Do I need to add any zstyle for ssh? @MarlonRichert

Comment: No, it should just work. I tried this in Zsh without loading any other config and it works fine. Have you checked the contents of the `hosts` files I listed above?

Comment: You can try this yourself: Do `cd "$(mktemp -d)"; ZDOTDIR=$PWD zsh -df` to start a sub shell without any config. In there, run `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`. Then type `ssh` and press Tab. If it works there, then you must have something in your `.zshrc` that messes it up. Try commenting out lines in your `.zshrc` until you find what causes it.

Comment: you are right. the problem is i have ```alias ssh='sshrc'``` in my zshrc. thanks.

Comment: ```compdef _ssh sshrc``` not working at all. but ```compdef _telnet sshrc``` is working.something weird is happening between ssh and sshrc script file.

Comment: https://github.com/alexshvid/sshrc/blob/master/sshrc

Comment: _ssh handles scp, sftp etc so will be confused by sshrc. Try `compdef _ssh sshrc=ssh` to treat sshrc like ssh.

Comment: This indeed solve the original question. I just want to point that, if some hosts inside .ssh/config include '*', then Zsh's completion will not work for them (bash does). Any solution?